# Arduino increment operators does not affect variable?

Tags: c, if-statement, arduino, increment, led

I am writing a program that interacts with the LED's connected on my breadboard that will simulate a "ball" bouncing up and down. Everything has worked correctly up until the point where the height of the bounce decrements (simulating loss of momentum). The LED's keep lighting on past the 9th LED and start acting bizarre.

The problems arose in this line of code:

```
digitalWrite(ledPin[activeLED], HIGH);
activeLED += dir;
 if (activeLED == bounceLimit){
   dir = -1;
   bounceLimit--;
 }
 if (activeLED == 0) {
  dir = 1;
 }
```

The activeLED is the LED being lit, they light in succession to the top until it hits the bounceLimit variable, where it changes direction and lights downward until zero and starts upwards again. The problem lies that in the next time it goes up, the bounceLimit should be set lower at 8 (then 7, 6, etc.) but it seems that it isn't set any lower and the LED's continue to light to the top and then start to act weird.

I managed to fix it by adding another condition

```
if (activeLED == bounceLimit && dir = 1){
dir = -1;
bounceLimit--;
}
```

But why is the extra condition needed? Wouldn't the limit be hit only when the direction is upwards (1) anyways?

Comment: You should probably look into the `else` statement ... or check what your variable values are.

Answer (score 0):

So if `bounceLimit` is (say) 9 to start, when you hit the top you take one away to make `bounceLimit` equal to 8.  But then when the LED goes down in the very next iteration the active LED is then also 8, which triggers your if statement again.